# Traduzione di titoli vari

Tags: translation, articles

Ho un compito di cui devo tradurre un brano. Una parte per esempio è «The letters from No One» con le lettere maiuscole di proposito.

Tradurrei come "Le lettere da nessuno" ma una traduzione officiale dice «Lettere da nessuno».

A cosa serve così? Quando l'articolo può essere rimosso?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE! Non capisco bene la tua domanda.

Comment: Le virgolette « non si ottengono con due segni “<”, che anzi rendono illeggibile il testo.

Comment: Puoi chiarire meglio? Che cos'è “The letters from No One”? Un titolo di un libro preesistente, di un film, una frase di qualcuno?

Comment: Mi scusi che non mi ho spiegato. “The letters from No One” è un capitolo di Harry Potter e volevo sapere sopratutto se ci fosse un ragione per mancare "Le" nella traduzione.

Comment: non ho capito il titolo della domanda "Traduzione di titoli vari": potresti modificarlo con qualcosa di più descrittivo?

Answer (score 2):

Chiarirò meglio la risposta quando la domanda sarà più chiara, ma se si deve citare il titolo di un libro, racconto, film etc. che sono stati pubblicati anche in italiano, la norma è di usare il titolo con cui sono apparsi in Italia, riportandolo con precisione anche se non è una traduzione letterale (quindi un articolo tolto o aggiunto è il meno).

Per esempio, se devo parlare in italiano del romanzo *The Catcher in the Rye* di J.D. Salinger, lo menzionerò col titolo con cui fu pubblicato ed è noto in Italia, e cioè *Il giovane Holden*, magari indicando tra parentesi, per completezza, anche il titolo originale. Nel caso specifico in cui il testo che sto traducendo analizzi qualche aspetto specifico del titolo originale (se cioè nel nostro esempio si parlasse della distinzione fra *rye* nel senso di “segale” e in quello di un tipo di whisky), chiarirò la cosa in nota o interpolando qualche parola nella traduzione.

[Un problema separato è quello di mantenere o meno l'integrità del titolo in situazioni come

> La prima versione dei *Promessi sposi*
>
> La prima versione di *I promessi sposi*
>
> La prima versione de *I promessi sposi*

L'ultima versione è da evitare perché non c'è motivo di usarla: “de” non è una parola della lingua italiana moderna: sarebbe una specie di preposizione articolata e poi disarticolata. La seconda versione va bene se è importante riferire letteralmente un titolo (magari la prima volta che lo si incontra). La prima versione è quella da utilizzare correntemente.]

Comment: È il titolo di un capitolo di uno degli “Harry Potter”. L'uso delle maiuscole nei titoli è normale nella tipografia anglosassone; quasi tutte le fonti trovate con Google riportano “The Letters From No One” (poche hanno “from” con la minuscola) che sembra strano, visto che preposizioni e congiunzioni in altri titoli dello stesso libro sono riportate minuscole. In italiano l'uso delle maiuscole nei titoli è molto meno comune (lo era in passato).

Comment: Grazie per aver trovato la fonte in Harry Potter, @egreg. In inglese è senz'altro la norma usare molte maiuscole: in quali parole di preciso, è una questione redazionale (con in più differenze fa BrE e AmE). In alcuni casi si usano le maiuscole per tutte le parole; più spesso si omettono articoli, preposizioni e congiunzioni a meno che non abbiano cinque o più lettere. Più lumi [qui](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14/which-words-in-a-title-should-be-capitalized).